# A better way to check If a user bookmarked a post

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a small bookmark feature for a site, where a user can bookmark a post. When a user bookmarks a post, it is added to the table `postMarks`.

The way I currently do it is to print the main posts from table `posts` and then `select count()` from the table `postMarks` for each `postId = id` and `userId = currentUser`. Is there a better, more efficient way to do this instead of having two separate statements running. The way I'm doing it is pretty inefficient I feel.

All my code is below. Since this still isn't implemented, I can make changes.

**posts**

```
"id"    "postTitle"
"1"     "Title 1"
"2"     "Title 2"
"3"     "Title 3"
"4"     "Title 4"
"5"     "Title 5"
"6"     "Title 6"
"7"     "Title 7"
"8"     "Title 8"
"9"     "Title 9"
"10"    "Title 10"
```

**postMarks**

```
"id"    "postId"    "postTitle" "userId"    "addDate"
"1"     "1"         "Title 1"   "1"         "2014-04-22 09:57:35"
"2"     "2"         "Title 2"   "1"         "2014-04-22 09:58:10"
"3"     "3"         "Title 3"   "1"         "2014-04-22 09:58:12"
"4"     "4"         "Title 4"   "1"         "2014-04-22 09:58:25"
"5"     "5"         "Title 5"   "1"         "2014-04-22 09:58:37"
"6"     "1"         "Title 1"   "2"         "2014-04-22 09:59:10"
"7"     "2"         "Title 2"   "2"         "2014-04-22 09:59:20"
"8"     "1"         "Title 1"   "3"         "2014-04-22 09:59:33"
"9"     "2"         "Title 2"   "3"         "2014-04-22 09:59:45"
"10"    "3"         "Title 3"   "3"         "2014-04-22 09:59:53"
```

**My Code**

```
$userId = 1;

$pageData = 'select id, postTitle from posts LIMIT 10';

$stmt = $conn->prepare($pageData);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bindColumn(1,$a);
$stmt->bindColumn(2,$b);

$posts = $stmt->rowCount();

if($posts >= 1) {

    while($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
        echo $a.' '.$b;

        // Bookmarks
        $bookMarks = "select count(postId) from postMarks where postId = '".$a."' and userId = '".$userId."'";

        $stmtx = $conn->prepare($bookMarks);

        $stmtx->execute();

        $stmtx->bindColumn(1,$a);

        $stmtx->fetch();

        if($a == 1) {
            echo ' Bookmarked <br>';
        } else {
            echo ' Not Bookmarked <br>';
        }           
        // Bookmarks detect ends
    }

} else {
    echo 'Nothing to display ';
}
```

**Results**

```
1 Title 1 Bookmarked
2 Title 2 Bookmarked
3 Title 3 Bookmarked
4 Title 4 Bookmarked
5 Title 5 Bookmarked
6 Title 6 Not Bookmarked
7 Title 7 Not Bookmarked
8 Title 8 Not Bookmarked
9 Title 9 Not Bookmarked
10 Title 10 Not Bookmarked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your sql query with a join. You should now be able to get a bool if the current user bookmarked the page.

```
$pageData = 'SELECT
                    id,
                    postTitle,
                    IF( count(distinct postMarks.userId) > 0, true, false) as bookmarkByUser
             FROM 
                    postsLEFT JOIN postMarks ON posts.id=postMarks.postId AND userId =".$userId."
             GROUP BY
                    post.idLIMIT 10';
```

Comment: Awesome work, but I'm actually trying to check if a particular user bookmarked a particular post or not. In this case, it's $userId = 1, see my edit **Results** to the question. I'm not trying to check how many times a post was bookmarked. If a user has bookmarked a post I need to print 'Bookmarked' else 'Not Bookmarked'

Comment: @Norman I updated it now with that logic implemented. You will now get a bool